# Get the exit code of a Python script in a Bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, exit-code

I'm new to Bash and want to catch my Python script exit code.

My `script.py` looks like:

```python
#! /usr/bin/python
def foofoo():
    ret = # Do logic
    if ret != 0:
        print repr(ret) + 'number of errors'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print 'NO ERRORS!!!!'
        sys.exit(0)

def main(argv):
    # Do main stuff
    foofoo()

if __main__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:]
```

My Bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
python script.py -a a1  -b a2 -c a3
if [ $?!=0 ];
then
    echo "exit 1"
fi
echo "EXIT 0"
```

My problem is that I am always getting `exit 1` printed in my Bash script. How can I get my Python exit code in my Bash script?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The spaces are important because they are the arguments delimiter:

```
if [ $? != 0 ];
then
    echo "exit 1"
fi
echo "EXIT 0"
```

Or numeric test `-ne`. See `man [` for `[` command or `man bash` for builtin more details.

```
# Store in a variable. Otherwise, it will be overwritten after the next command
exit_status=$?
if [ "${exit_status}" -ne 0 ];
then
    echo "exit ${exit_status}"
fi
echo "EXIT 0"
```